# Uso de IN o EXISTS en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para la universidad en donde debo hacer un sistema de gestión de viajes, en donde tengo tablas como `Pasajeros`, `Viaje`, `Boleto` etc. Ahora debo hacer consultas basándome en esta base que creé.

Una consulta en particular no he podido hacer funcionar, en esta tengo que listar los datos de los trenes que tengan mas de 20 asientos los cuales no tengan asignados ningún viaje para el día de mañana, lo cual sería la columna `DATETIME FechaHoraViaje`.

```
DECLARE     @Fecha DATE

SET         @Fecha = DATEADD(DAY, +1, GETDATE())

SELECT      t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren,
            CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE)

FROM        dbo.Tren        AS  t
JOIN        dbo.Viaje       AS  v   ON  v.IdTren = t.IdTren

WHERE       @Fecha IN (SELECT CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE)
                       FROM dbo.Viaje AS v
                       WHERE CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE) = '2017-06-08')

AND         CapacidadTren       > 20

GROUP BY    t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren,
            CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE)
```

En la parte del `WHERE` uso `IN` para comparar mi variable `@Fecha` con el resultado de la subquery, que sería exactamente la fecha de mañana.
El resultado debería ser la información del único tren que no tiene viajes asignados para mañana, pero en cambio me devuelve la información de ambos trenes, no entiendo cual es la lógica para devolverme ambos trenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El resultado que estas obteniendo son todos los trenes que tienen un viaje para la fecha `2016-06-08`, eso es lo que expresa tu consulta al joinear ambas tablas y tener en cuenta los viajes para esa fecha en particular mediante el `IN`

Si lo que quieres es obtener todos los trenes que NO tienen un viaje para una fecha dada (parámetro @Fecha) esa parte de tu consulta deberia ser:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM dbo.Viaje AS v
                       WHERE CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE) = @Fecha and v.idTren = t.idTren)
```

Esta subquery filtraria cuando para un idTren no este referenciado en la tabla dbo.Viaje para la fecha `2017-06-08`

Tu consulta quedaria:

```
DECLARE     @Fecha DATE

SET         @Fecha = DATEADD(DAY, +1, GETDATE())

SELECT      t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren,
            CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE)

FROM        dbo.Tren        AS  t
JOIN        dbo.Viaje       AS  v   ON  v.IdTren = t.IdTren

  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM dbo.Viaje AS v
                           WHERE CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE) = @Fecha and 

AND         CapacidadTren       > 20

GROUP BY    t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren,
            CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE)
```

Comment: esto me funcionó, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estas filtrando adecuadamente en la subconsulta, ya que esta no verifica si el tren actual del set de datos tiene trenes el día siguiente, sino que no exista ningún tren con viajes en día siguiente, lo otro que veo extraño es que quieres la lista de trenes, y que estos salgan solo una vez, pero pones la fecha del viaje, esto hace que el tren salga mas de una vez
Este es un ejemplo de 2 maneras de hacerlo.

```
DECLARE     @Fecha DATE

SET         @Fecha = DATEADD(DAY, +1, GETDATE())

SELECT      t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren

FROM         @Tren       AS  t   
WHERE           CapacidadTren       > 20 and 
not exists(select 1 from @Viaje v1 where cast(v1.FechaHoraViaje as date)=@Fecha and t.IdTren = v1.IdTren)

SELECT      t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren


FROM         @Tren       AS  t
left JOIN        @Viaje       AS  v   ON  v.IdTren = t.IdTren   and cast(FechaHoraViaje as date)= @Fecha
WHERE           CapacidadTren       > 20 and 
v.IdViaje is null
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observación 1**: No se requiere una subconsulta sabiendo que ya estás haciendo un `JOIN` a `dbo.Viaje`.

**Observación 2**: Al utilizar `DATEADD(DAY, +1, GETDATE())`, simplemente estás agregando un día a la fecha actual, es decir, suponiendo que la fecha y hora actual son `2017/06/09 12:40:20`, al sumar un día a la fecha actual obtendrás `2017/06/10 12:40:20`, entonces, si algún viaje sale después de esa hora quedará fuera de la consulta.

La solución consiste en quitar la subconsulta y poner:

```
WHERE       CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, +1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
AND         CapacidadTren       > 20
```

Con esto, se estarían seleccionando los viajes que cumplan con esas condiciones.

Código completo (por cierto, tampoco necesitas declarar ninguna variable):

```
SELECT      t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren,
            CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE)

FROM        dbo.Tren        AS  t
JOIN        dbo.Viaje       AS  v   ON  v.IdTren = t.IdTren

WHERE       CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, +1, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
AND         CapacidadTren       > 20

GROUP BY    t.IdTren,
            t.TipoTren,
            t.CapacidadTren,
            t.MarcaTren,
            CAST(v.FechaHoraViaje AS DATE)
```